# AVAudioPlayer stops when audio input is added to AVCaptureSession

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, avcapturesession

I'm working on karaoke app. It should record video with sound of a user singing a song. Lyrics and melody are are provided by app.

With video recording everything was fine until I've added audio input to AVCaptureSession. Problem is with AVAudioPlayer that plays melody - it just stops when AVCaptureSession starts. I did not find any restrictions on that in Apple docs.

Did anyone have experience with recording sound in AVCaptureSession simultaneously with playing sound via AVAudioPlayer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869802/avcapturesession-and-background-audio-ios-7

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is due to having more than one audio sessions at the same time. I am not sure whether this will be supported.Anyway it will be better if you try it with different session categories.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to set the audio to mix with other:

```
- (void)setupAudio {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
    UInt32 doSetProperty = 1;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(doSetProperty), &doSetProperty);
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
}
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411793/avassetreader-kills-playback-in-avaudioplayer/7426406#7426406)